# SSD or Virtual Memory? It's possible?

Tags: memory, ssd, mac-mini

I bought a MacMini, which configuration is: 1.4 GHz Intel Core i5 Dual-Cor, 4 GB 1600 MHz DDR3 and 256 GB SSD. Using the machine, I noticed it's a little slow for my purpose. So I would like to know if buying an external SSD would give me more speed... would that be a possible solution? Also, is it possible to create a "virtual memory" on MacOSX? Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: No, adding an external drive will do nothing for your speed.  This is a slow machine.  Memory is probably not your issue but since you don't mention what you are actually using it for, that is difficult to answer.  Hard drive I/O is certainly not your issue.  From experience I say (and somewhat opinionated), macmini machines are not fast.  I have tried to use them for mac build machines (because apple only allows you to build apple on apple) and they were unforgivably slow.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - The new M1s are pretty zippy. That particular mini is the slowest they ever sold. They also unfortunately have soldered RAM so you can't increase it. Virtual memory is system managed & is usually pretty good on Macs. There is no way to adjust it manually.

Comment: Thanks for the information @Tetsujin :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need more memory than physical memory, the system will page some pages out of the RAM to the SSD. And since SSD accesses are far slower than RAM (the system has to transfer the accessed pages back to RAM), the system will slow down.

Adding SSD won’t change anything : your average memory access won’t change. The only way to avoid slow performance with a system with too less RAM (compared to the needs), is more memory.

Virtual memory is already what you have with a system which use a drive (SSD) to compensate the lack of memory. Inconvenience : the system is slowed down when the memory use is more than physical memory. Advantage : you don’t have a message « memory exhausted » or something like this when too much memory is needed.

Note : 4GB is low for a nowadays system, this doesn’t surprise me that you suffer slowness. On my 8GB system, I avoid using Firefox and a Digital Audio Workstation (DAW) together : Firefox is memory hungry and my DAW is not too hungry but quite sensitive about performance.